# Cannot acces BIOS after setting HDD password

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, boot, bios, passwords

I have a Lenovo G580 that had Windows 8 pre-installed which was upgraded to Windows 10. I set the HDD password one day but now I cannot access the BIOS or the boot menu. Even if I use the "One Touch Recovery Tool", soon as the system begins to boot, it prompts me for the HDD password and loads Windows. I would really like to be able to access the BIOS and boot menu but I am at a loss.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Even if you hold down the F2 key before you start to boot?

Answer (score 0):

you must replace CMOS battery in your laptop motherboard and turn on your laptop without CMOS, after you run OS turn it off,after that install again CMOS battery on your laptop then turn on.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work. I even left both batteries out over night, used the one touch recovery button, chose "BIOS Setup" but then it prompted me for the HDD password then booted Windows soon as I entered the password. I've tried every Function key, esc., Delete, and even different combinations with Shift, Ctrl, and Alt. No matter what as soon as I turn the PC on it immediately prompts me for the HDD password then boots Windows. I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows 10 try disabling fast start up and shutting down your pc. Then power up and press <kbd>F2</kbd> and it should work (it will still ask you for the HDD password and the BIOS admin password) and the BIOS should load.